# Expert description of data visualization figures

Tags: data-visualization, references

There are good sources that teach the different kinds of plots to visualize data analysis results. Especially there are some good statistics books that show different plots to visualize data in various ways.

In research papers, however, beyond insightful plots one needs to also describe the technical details of the figure in the best possible way. Are there books or websites that list out research data-plots and then couple it with quality technical descriptions that are professional and technical in nature?

For example, there is a simple bar plot.

[image]

Now what is the most expert technical description I could come up with to write **in a research paper**? Maybe something like:

"The number of cars are shown to be strictly decreasing with the number of gears with an average drop of 20% per unit increase in the number of gears."

In the above example, could you describe more numerical details? Could you explore the technical details of the plot in a more expert way? These are the types of questions on which I seek expert supervision all collected in one place.

Are there online resources that do this for various examples on data visualization?

Comment: Are you asking how to describe this plot in words? In many cases the general rule is not to duplicate information, so rather then describing what is on the plot, you would rather comment the results.

Comment: i am asking about describing plots in words+numbers in an expert way so that it does not feel very simplistic. for example if there is a heatmap, what numerical details i should mention which won't be obvious to a reader just by looking at the heatmap. And i want to do this in a way that seems sophisticated. the bar plot is a very trivial example. i should have chosen a better example.

Comment: What best to say about a plot depends on much more than expertise. What's worth commenting on depends on the readership, the data, the goals of a project and what is known generally about the extent (so what is expected, banal, surprising, shocking...). For example, the wording appropriate to the bar chart you show could be quite different without being wrong or less or more expert. I can't think that there is, or even could be, a source with what you want.

Comment: @Nick I agree. However, I wouldn't want readers to deduce from your remarks that the likely absence of a good resource for describing statistical graphics implies this question is bad or should not be asked. (I don't think you intended to make such an implication.) My experience, at least, suggests that many people who use graphics for communication could use advice on how to do it better--myself included. For that reason, perhaps the largest section of books on my shelf focuses on graphical communication: these books convey effective *principles* of lasting value.

Comment: @whuber Indeed. my comment at its simplest could be "I don't think there is such a source". It could continue "and I doubt that you what seek could exist". A more positive spin could be that the best sources give examples of good practice, but that is the point: They teach by example as much as precept. No source can tell you what you should write for the figure that you have in front of you. Still, generic advice might start: What are the broad features of this plot? Are there interesting, informative or striking details that you want to flag for your readers too?

Comment: @whuber Could you list some of the books that you find most useful in this regard?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are asking, but I think that you are asking for the wrong thing. Asking for descriptions that are "technical", "sophisticated", "professional" and so on seems to be asking for the wrong thing. Even in a highly technical publication, the goal should be descriptions that are clear and simple. 

One of the great things about good graphics is that they make insight possible through a "Behold!" insight rather than through technical description.

Comment: @Peter There are too many to list, but chief among them are books by Tufte, Cleveland *et al.,* Wilkinson, Wainer, Tukey, Bertin, and MacEachren.

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica I agree

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as Nick Cox says, how to describe a figure is unanswerable without context - of the field, audience, question, study design, and more.